# Slower canvas in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, canvas, easeljs

http://jsfiddle.net/2247N/

I made this jsFiddle that uses EaselJS from CreateJS to update a simple canvas on defined frame rate of 60 FPS. There is just a simple circle on the stage, so I would expect the FPS label to show constant 60FPS on every browser. But here's what I've found:

**Chrome:** `FPS: 60.82474226801933`

**IE:** `FPS: 60.095788862740555`

**Firefox:** `FPS: 43.2232327656598`

Why not also `60FPS` in Firefox? I am using Firefox 29.0.1. No other tabs were opened, cache was cleared, window was active, no other applications were running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

slower canvas speed seems to be a trend with Firefox.

On my machine, I get a solid 59-60, but for best practices, you may want to use `requestAnimationFrame` as 2astalavista mentioned in conjunction with setting FPS. To do that in CreateJS, just set the timing mode to `RAF_SYNCHED`:

```
createjs.Ticker.timingMode = createjs.Ticker.RAF_SYNCHED;
createjs.Ticker.setFPS(60);
```

Documentation on Timing Modes: http://www.createjs.com/tutorials/Animation%20and%20Ticker/

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2247N/1/

Comment: Thanks for posting this, I see it is much better than the standard Ticker, I will use it.

Answer (score 2):

In case someone still has this problem, try removing the shadows on all objects because Firefox is performing poorly when it's trying to render shadows on the canvas. More information [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-gaming-benchmarking-sprite-animations/):